# text mining in sqlite

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, data-mining, text-mining

I have sqlite database and need to find the most frequent words in it.
Example,

> text
>   table chair floor
>   table chair
>   table

Solution needed

> word number
>   table  3
>   chair  2
>   floor  1

The database is big (several Gb). I am looking for solution in SQL. Also maybe using C++ or other approach.

Comment: In what area do you need help? Acessing a sqlite database from C++ or formulating a sql statement that does the job?

Comment: formulating sql statement that does the job

Comment: Please provide a description of your database table structure in your question.

Comment: real table has only 2 columns: user_id, comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html

Check out the  *Fts4aux - Direct Access to the Full-Text Index* section.

Comment: It will be a select-statement against the index file, sorting by [occurrences] in descending sort order.

Answer (score 3):

Sqlite does not have any command, that would allow generating multiple rows from single string (and can't easily have; such thing requires "unpack" extension to SQL). So you'll need an application code to split the comments to words. Than you can either create a table where you insert each word on a separate line and than `select word, count(rowid) from words group by word`, or you can directly count the words using hash map in the application.